# Página de inicio en blanco per o las demás funcionan perfectamente Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

¿qué tal?

Tengo un problema y les agradecería mucho si me ayudan.

He creado una web en wordpress y woocommerce y todo funciona bien. Sin embargo, a veces no carga la página de inicio (Sí, sólo la página de inicio. Las demás sí cargan sin problema. He intentando cambiándola o poniendo una en blanco e igual sigue sin funcionar). Lo más extraño es que no muestra ningún error, sólo un mensaje "result: ok".

Les mostraré la pantalla que se muestra a veces y también cómo se ve cuando carga.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El único mensaje de error que me muestra es en el archivo debug.log pero tampoco me da mucha información.

[23-Jun-2021 22:54:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  is_offline was called **incorrectly**. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home2/sgrchil/sp3market.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

[23-Jun-2021 22:54:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  is_500 was called **incorrectly**. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home2/sgrchil/sp3market.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313.

También les mostraré la línea de código en donde se supone que se muestra el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error lleva semanas y sólo aparece de vez en cuando. Incluso, creé la página nuevamente desde cero para ver si de esta manera se solucionaba el error, pero no. Sigue apareciendo y no sé si esté relacionado con el servidor (Hostgator). Cabe añadir que tengo una web similar en este hostinger y todo funciona bien (https://eldominio.net).

Si les ha pasado o tienen idea de qué podría ser, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Si sucede de vez en cuanto entonces es complicado replicar ese error, sin embargo basado en como se ve diría que sucede por alguna llamada que algún archivo js esta haciendo, puede que sea por recaptcha, recomiendo que la próxima vez que suceda revises la consola para verificar que errores te arroja para intentar detectar así porque sucede.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Bueno, la consola no me muestra nada prácticamente. Sólo esto:

Comment: 01-Jul-2021 07:02:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  is_offline was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home2/sgrchil/sp3market.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

Comment: [01-Jul-2021 07:02:56 UTC] PHP Notice:  is_500 was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home2/sgrchil/sp3market.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313